# Problems with そうです in this sentence

Tags: grammar, auxiliaries

> 留守番電話に伝言入れたのに、それを ***聞かなかったそうです*** 。

So, the problem I have is the following:

In my textbook, I learned that ます-stem + そうです means "to seem", like "雨が降りそうです。"

Then, dictionary form + そうです means hearsay, like:

> 田中さんは出張するそうです。

In this sentence we're talking about, strictly speaking we have neither dictionary form nor masu-stem. We simply have non-polite past.
So, does this construction even express one of the two things I explained, or is そうです in another function here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### ***Inference vs. Hearsay***

### **Inference**:

Words and their forms that must directly precede 「そう（だ/です/である, etc.）」 are:

> - Verbs in 連用形{れんようけい} (continuative form)
> - Subsidiary Verbs (れる、られる、せる、させる) in 連用形
> - Adjective Stems with the exceptions of 「ない」 and 「よい」, where you must say 「な**さ**そう」 and 「よ**さ**そう」 with an extra さ thrown in. ← Important!
> - Stems of Subsidiary Verbs ない and たい

Examples:

> 「雨{あめ}が降{ふ}りそうだ。」
> 「また先生{せんせい}に[怒]{おこ}られそうです。」
> 「明日{あした}も寒{さむ}そうだよね。」
> 「この映画{えいが}はよ**さ**そうだな。」 よい used as an adjective
> 「あの人は眠{ねむ}たそうだ。」
> 「誰{だれ}も知{し}らなそうだ。」 ない used as a subsidiary verb

(If you could turn all these inference sentences into hearsay ones, you probably know the subject matter well.  I do encounter ***many*** mistakes with this made by J-learners if I may be honest here.)

### **Hearsay**:

Words and their forms that must directly precede 「そう（だ/です/である, etc.）」 are:

> - Dictionary forms and their past-tense forms of Verbs and Adjectives.
> - Vast majority of subsidiary verbs in their dictionary forms and the past tense-forms.  The most famous exception would be 「です」.  You cannot say 「ですそうだ」, 「でしたそうです」, etc.

Examples:

> 「留守番電話{るすばんでんわ}に伝言{でんごん}入{い}れたのに、それを聞{き}かなかったそうです。」
> 「タローは６時{じ}までには帰{かえ}れるそうよ。ジローは無理{むり}みたい。」

Comment: また先生に**おこられ**そうです => looks like honorific form of くる? I don't know, what is it? :D  If its passive I have problems with it as well, whats it supposed to mean then, "to be visited"?

Comment: @Narktor It's [怒]{おこ}られそうです. 怒られる is the passive form of 怒る, "to be mad at", "to scold" (≂ [叱]{しか}る).